# How do I reset an incremental variable inside a for loop (python)?

Tags: python, for-loop

python newb here so apologies for the extremely basic question, but I have tried to figure this out via generic google searches and can't seem to get the answer I'm looking for. So, I beseech the stackoverflow gods to help me...

Here's my scenario:

I have a directory, with multiple subdirectories and multiple files within those subdirectories. The subdirectories represent one digital object (a physical book), and the files inside are .tif files that correspond to the objects "pages." I want to be able to iterate over these subdirectories and to count the number of .tif files within them, but for each subdirectory, I want the count to begin back at 1, thus representing the "page numbers" of that "book."

All I can seem to figure out is how to count the files, in a linear progression. Here's the code I've been using:

```
Label = 0
for rootDir, subdir, filenames in os.walk('/Users/kaylaheslin/Desktop/mets_test'):
    for filename in fnmatch.filter(filenames, "*.tif"):
        Label += 1
        print(Label)
```

Of course, this walks through the files and adds one each time a .tif file is found, but I need to begin @ 1 for each subdirectory. Someone, please help! I want to know what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Would swapping the first two lines do what you want?

```py
for rootDir, subdir, filenames in os.walk('/Users/kaylaheslin/Desktop/mets_test'):
    Label = 0
    for filename in fnmatch.filter(filenames, "*.tif"):
        Label += 1
        print(Label)
```

This way you reset `Label` on every pass through the outer loop. In other words, each time you drop into a new subdirectory you start the count from 0 again.

Also, if you want to associate a number with each file, perhaps you could avoid a counter variable in the first place:

```py
for rootDir, subdir, filenames in os.walk('/Users/kaylaheslin/Desktop/mets_test'):
    tif_files = fnmatch.filter(filenames, "*.tif")

    for i, file in enumerate(tif_files):
        print(i)
```

Comment: Hi! Thank you for your suggestions. Ultimately, I want to use this information to build METs for the objects, and so I need to have a page number for each tif file, but your first script suggestion accomplishes that!

Comment: Glad to hear it! You may wish to mark the answer as accepted unless you'd like to get more opinions. It may be worth looking at `enumerate`, which is a shorthand for `zip(range(len(L)), L)` where L is a list. I will add it to the answer

Answer (score 0):

You can create a dictionary of each folder name and the file count:

```
import os

Label = 0
dd = {}
for rootDir, subdir, filenames in os.walk('/Users/kaylaheslin/Desktop/mets_test'):
    for filename in filenames:
        if filename.endswith('.tif'):
            if rootDir in dd:
               dd[rootDir]+=1
            else:
               dd[rootDir]=1

for k in dd:
  print(k,dd[k])
```